# need help with script options in terminal/bash

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm fairly new to scripting (self teacher), but not clueless.
im trying to make and easy installer script for a program version set, and am running into some difficulties.
here is a modified version of the code

(

```
echo "deb http://blah.blahblah.net/blah/blah/ubuntu precise main" | tee/etc/apt/sources.list.d/blahblah.list
echo "deb-src http://blah.blahblah.net/blah/blah/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/blahblah.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys blah000000
apt-get update

`
echo "please select the Version of blah you want ************  1)blah1    2)blah2 3)blah3 4)All (1,2,3) 5)I will do this manualy (in the software center)"

read n
case $n in
    1) apt-get install blah1;;
    2) apt-get install blah2;;
    3) apt-get install blah3;;
    4) apt-get install blah1 blah2 blah3;;
    5) echo "Thank you and have a nice day. :-)"   exit;;
    *) invalid option;;
esac
```

)

It will finish the apt update, but gives me this message afterwards

(

```
blah 1-2-3-installer_beta.sh: 22: blah 1-2-3-installer_beta.sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
```

)

any suggestions ..... 
(side note: the "blah"'s don't matter I've already checked)

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 "Trusty" and Linux Mint 17.3 "cinnamon"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one backquote (`` ` ``) in you code but it is not complemented by the ending backquote. It's not clear what are you up to with the backquotes.

Backquotes are used for command substitution, also start using `$()` for command substitution instead of older and problematic backquotes.

To solve your current problem, just comment out the single backquote (`` ` ``) after the `apt-get update` line i.e.:

```
apt-get update

# `
echo "please select the Version of blah you want ************  1)blah1    2)blah2 3)blah3 4)All (1,2,3) 5)I will do this manualy (in the software center)"
```

Comment: thank you, i took you suggestion and that helped out a lot... i just don't want anyone to know exactly what it its yet is all